# combining IF with Concatenate to get desired result with a "." between and no spaces

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

Hi I have Microsoft Office Professional 2013.

I'm using instructions from 2014 to add a formula to a spreadsheet to combine task and subtask into one column. The formula as written returns error #NAME?.

```
G Col.      H Col.          I Added column to combine 1st and 2nd.
Task Number Subtask Number  TaskSubtask Number
                            (desired result)
1                           1.0
1            1              1.1
1            2              1.2
```

there are 2624 rows.

most columns in the subtask number are blank. Some have a subtask number.

Here is the formula previously used:

```
=if(H2=””,concatenate(G2,”.0”),concatenate(G2,”.”,H2))
```

When I try to use the check formula, and change concatenate to concat the only error is in the first part `if(H2="",`

I've looked all over, Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Or `=G2+H2/10` Then format the cell as `#.0`

Comment: Or if your h column will be more than one digit: `=G2+H2/10^len(H2)`

Comment: humm  =G2&"."&H2*1 returns only .0

Comment: how do you format cell as #.0? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong kind of double-quotes:

```
=IF(H2="",CONCATENATE(G2,".0"),CONCATENATE(G2,".",H2))
```

Comment: HI thanks for whatever reason it also returns only .0.   I want it to say 1.0. Just can't figure out what each segment should do. The double quotes came from copying from word that make sense they aren't right..i"ll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H2),CONCATENATE(G2,".0"),CONCATENATE(G2,".",H2))
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks everyone - this almost worked...it returned .0 only
it should be 1.0....I'll keep trying things and the others above thanks